# SharePoint 2013 View document insert

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, file-upload

I have created a New column in a Doc Library. Column is a Choice Field.
It's called Catalog. There are Three Choices in the Catalog: 1,2,3.
I have also created views which shows documents that have Choice 1, 2, 3 as Metadata.

Now I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to insert a large Swath of files through IE View when I'm in View 1, to automatically add Choice 1 in the Catalog, Choose Choice 2 when in view 2, choose 3 when in view 3.

I have turned off the versioning, the requirement to check out documents so I can insert massive amounts of files. But I need the files to choose between 1,2,3 .... I want to know if it's possible to bind the Choice towards the active view?

Answer (score 0):

An Event Receiver may check if we're running in an HTTP context (`HttpContext.Current != null`). If so, it may check the URL referer. From that referer, the current View may be checked, and the metadata set accordingly.